# Need help indexing a list in BIRT Report Designer

Tags: javascript, birt, rpt

I have a list ( not advanced, only one key value) that will be used to generate a table in an rptdesign file. 
What I need to do is have each of these list/table entries indexed as 1,2,3,....n 
Would there be an auto number setting in BIRT that can allow me to do so or would I need to script it in? If so, where would I input the script. 
Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the expression `row.__rownum + 1`

`row.__rownum` is 0 for the first row, 1 for the second row, and so on.
If there aren't any rows, row.__rownum is -1, which is useful inside a visibility expression for list/table items.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.
That helped a lot!